# Schematics PolyModelType How to choose correct model if field-condition is placed level up

Tags: python, polymodel

I have the following models e.g How to choose correct model under PolyModel based on "code" value that placed level up into the structure?
Thanks in advance

```
class _Model1(Model):
    resourceId = StringType()
    resourceType = StringType()

class _Model2(Model):
    description = ModelType(_Model1)

def claim_func(..):
    if code == 1:
        return _Model1
    elif code == 2:
        return _Model2

class TestModel(Model):
    code = IntType(required=True)
    message = StringType(required=True)
    details = PolyModelType([_Model1, _Model2], claim_function=claim_func)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's basically not the decision to be made upon the Model's field, but the data's field, as per the following code snippet demonstrates:

```
def claim_func(field, data):
  if 1 == data["code"]:
    return _Model1
  ...
```